# Determining rating scale based off the options

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to rate each value with a scale. How can I determine the rest of the ratings below?

- less weight is better
- rating scale from 0-10. 10 being the best

  - 2.32 lbs - 10
  - 2.47 lbs
  - 2.55 lbs
  - 2.87 lbs
  - 2.88 lbs
  - 2.9 lbs
  - 3.7 lbs
  - 3.86 lbs
  - 3.9 lbs
  - 3.97 lbs
  - 4 lbs
  - 4.3 lbs
  - 5.07 lbs
  - 9.12 lbs

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! If the answer you received meets your requirements, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem want a non-negative decreasing function of mass in pounds where $f(2.32)=10$.

There are a large number of possibilities.  One is $$f(x) = \frac{23.2}{x}.$$

For your example values, this gives (to two decimal places)

```
 x              f(x)
2.32 lbs        10
2.47 lbs        9.39
2.55 lbs        9.10
2.87 lbs        8.08
2.88 lbs        8.06
2.9  lbs        8
3.7  lbs        6.27
3.86 lbs        6.01
3.9  lbs        5.95
3.97 lbs        5.84
4    lbs        5.8
4.3  lbs        5.40
5.07 lbs        4.58
9.12 lbs        2.54
```